# Using UnityEventTools.RemovePersistentListener

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating an editor script that creates UI buttons and add listeners with arguments. I have completed that. Now, I want to remove the listeners with code.

The unity documentation for this isn't much help.

Code:

```
GameObject my_UIPanel;

// Destroy panel and buttons that were created previously.

my_UIPanel = GameObject.Find ("Panel_RoomButtons");
Button[] myBtns = my_UIPanel.GetComponentsInChildren<Button> ();
foreach (Button myBtn in myBtns) 
{
    // This is the thing giving me a headache. Rest everything works fine.
    UnityEventTools.RemovePersistentListener(myBtn.onClick, myUIManager.DEV_myFunction); 
}
if (my_UIPanel != null) 
    DestroyImmediate (my_UIPanel);

// Create new panel and buttons.

my_UIPanel = Instantiate(Pnl_RoomBtnsPrefab) as GameObject;

foreach (GameObject emptyLocation in teleLocations) 
{
    GameObject myBtnGO = Instantiate (teleBtnPrefab) as GameObject;
    myBtnGO.name = emptyLocation.name + "Btn";
    myBtnGO.transform.SetParent (my_UIPanel.transform, false);
    GameObject currentGO = emptyLocation;
    Button myBtn = myBtnGO.GetComponent <Button> ();
    UnityEventTools.AddObjectPersistentListener(myBtn.onClick, myUIManager.DEV_myFunction, currentGO);
}
```

If you can help me solve this, I'd be grateful for your help.

Thanks!

EDIT: These are the errors I'm getting

Assets/Scripts/RIGScripts/Editor/WorkspaceSetupEditor.cs(247,65): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEditor.Events.UnityEventTools.RemovePersistentListener(UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase, int)' has some invalid arguments

Assets/Scripts/RIGScripts/Editor/WorkspaceSetupEditor.cs(247,65): error CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert`method group' expression to type `int'

in this line:

```
UnityEventTools.RemovePersistentListener(myBtn.onClick, myUIManager.DEV_myFunction);
```

Comment: Can you give as a hint what is the problem? You have any exception or what?

Comment: @RajSharma add these errors to your question and also tell at which lines you are getting these errors

Comment: @UmairM done. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't realize this before. I got it to work.

```
UnityEventTools.RemovePersistentListener(myBtn.onClick, 0);
```

I was supposed to pass the index of the method and not the method name.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try using specific class `ButtonClickedEvent`.

**Remove Listeners:**

```
myBtn.onClick.RemoveListener(methodName);
```

or

```
myBtn.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
```

**Add Listener:**

```
myBtn.OnClick.AddListener(methodName);
```

[Read More](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button.ButtonClickedEvent.html)

---

## UPDATE:

**For Editor Mode:**

try this:

```
UnityEventTools.AddPersistentListener(myBtn.onClick, new UnityAction(methodName));
```

Comment: That didn't work. I used AddObjectPersistentListener because I'm creating the UI buttons in the editor and each of them need a "GameObject" as a parameter. I used AddListener before but that didn't work. But that's not the problem. It's working perfectly except for the part where I need to remove the Listeners from the button. I tried using RemoveAllListeners which didn't work. I get an error when I use RemoveListener(methodName) I think it's because my method requires a GameObject as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.

Try this:

```
UnityEventTools.RemovePersistentListener<TYPE_OF_PARAMETER>(myBtn.onClick, myUIManager.DEV_myFunction);
```

This was the solution in my case :)